# What is the purpose of the Intellij Commander?

Tags: intellij-idea

Can somebody tell me what the purpose of the Intellij Commander is?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

http://jetbrains.net/devnet/docs/DOC-17 :

The two-panel Commander paradigm is a way of representing a hierarchy which provides the following benefits when working with the project elements:

1. In contrast to the tree-mode views, the Commander always shows only one hierarchy level which is rather convenient in many situations (e.g. when you are permanently working only with one package and don't want or just don't need to view the entire hierarchy-tree)
2. It provides a very convenient interface for copying and moving packages/classes (i.e., when using copy/move operations in one of the two panels, the destination is automatically suggested according to the location currently expanded in the opposite panel). For details on the operations available from the Commander, please look at the popup menus that appears when you right-click on different nodes in the commander tree. These menus are context-dependent and allow different operations on the elements of different types.

If you don't use it, you can always disable the Commander plug-in in Settings | Plugins.

Comment: I guess it's for the fans of Norton Commander, Midnight Commander, Far, Total Commander and similar file managers with 2 panels. I don't use it, external Total Commander is my choice.

Comment: I've been using intellij since version 3. I have never used Commander.

Comment: I love the commander. Especially when editing large (Django) projects with many same-named files spread over different packages, I find that I can navigate more easily using the commander (then again, I used to be a heavy Norton Commander user). I also make extensive use of "search everywhere" and "navigate | file" shortcuts, but commander sometimes works better. (you can search as you type, enter, backspace to go up dir, etc.)

Comment: The explanation of JetBrains actually does not explain anything to me.  It looks like the commander window can help if you work with more than one top-level module in your project, and want to copy code between two such modules.  The commander windows would be quite more helpful, if it were able to work with remote (SFTP etc.) files, too, in case both have diverged.  But it looks like it only supports local files.